# How to iterate this code 10 times through

Tags: recursion, racket, tail-recursion

Here's the question:

> Write a tail recursive function that takes as input two non-negative integers P and k and outputs a list of the first 10 years of a population that has initial population P and multiplies the population by k every year. Your function can have helper variables if you want.

I was trying to get code to form a list with ten numbers. I assumed that the input for number would be 10. I tried to go in the direction of making the base case empty instead of 0. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this code or to make it better?

```
(define (pop2 P k number)
 (cond
   [(= number 0) '()]
   [else
   (append (pop2 k (* P k)(- number 1)(list P)))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. A recursive function definition is **tail-recursive** if nothing needs to be done after recursive call(s). But `pop2` has `append` around the recursive call!  To make sure that the function returns exactly what the recursive call returns, that keeps track of the result using an extra parameter to the function (an accumulator).
2. In the  recursive call, the arguments don't match up with their corresponding meaning, and there is an extra arg too:

```
(pop2    k    (* P k)    (- number 1)   (list P))
(pop2    P    k          number         ???)
```

---

Here's something that can get you started:

```
;; pop2-acc : Nat Nat Nat [Listof Nat] -> [Listof Nat]
(define (pop2-acc P k number acc)
  (cond
    [(= number 0) <???>]
    [else (pop2-acc P k (- number 1) <???>)]))


;; pop2 : Nat Nat Nat -> [Listof Nat]
;; initial-population (P), factor (k), years (number)
(define (pop2 P k number)
  (pop2-acc P k number acc))
```

Note that `acc` is "the result so far." The helper `pop2-acc` could be turned into a local function within `pop2`, and we wouldn't have to pass in `k` into `pop2-acc` (because it stays the same).